# Simple closure dilemma

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get a better fundamental understandings of JavaScript's closure

say we have these two different scenarios in Node.js

```
function A(){

 console.log(data);  //this should give us a null pointer

}


module.exports = function(data){

    return A;

}
```

versus

```
module.exports = function(data){

   return function A(){

     console.log(data); // variable "data" will be remembered

   };

}
```

why is it that in the first case the variable "data" is not remembered but in the latter case it is "remembered" by the closure?

I am sure in some language somewhere, declaring a function and referencing a function might both remember the variables in the outer function, but I guess I want to better understand the difference.

Comment: There is a great community wiki on this at [How do JavaScript closures work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

Closures are about **lexical inclusion**. The word "lexical" in this context refers to the textual structure of the program, and "lexical inclusion" means that one construct is physically found "inside", or nested within, another. In JavaScript, functions have access to variables which are defined in lexically surrounding (enclosing) structures.

Therefore, in the following:

```
function foo() {
  var bar;
  return function baz() {
    console.log(bar);
  };
}
```

The function `baz` is lexically included within `foo`, which defines the variable `bar`, and therefore has access to `bar`. It continues to have access to `bar` even when it is returned and invoked from elsewhere:

```
var fooFunc = foo();
fooFunc();            // continues to have access to bar
```

In your example:

```
function A(){
  console.log(data);  //this should give us a null pointer
}

module.exports = function(data) {
  return A;
}
```

`A` does not have access to `data`, since it is not lexically included within the context of the function defined on the `module.exports` line, which is where `data` is defined (or in this case, passed in).

Answer (score 0):

you are using closure for variable `data` in the second case , that's why it gives you the correct result.

In the first case you are just return the function `A`, not closing over `data` variable in `exports`.

Answer (score 0):

Because in your first example, the two `data` are not related and are independent of each other.